# On an ASP.NET 4.x MVC application, if I make a minor change, do I have to recompile everything?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Not sure I'm using the right terminology, but if I have a website, and I make a change to one of the files, the underlying logic C#, whatever, do I have compile the whole application again before I deploy it?

How do I publish a small change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep saying "the whole thing", but you don't really seem to understand what that means.

An MVC application is a Web Application project, which means that it's class files are compiled into an assembly.  When you make a change to a class, the assembly that it's in must be recompiled (as well as any assemblies that are dependent upon it) and redeployed.

You don't have to recompile other assemblies that have not been changed, and you don't have to redeploy any unchanged files (like views or css or javascript).

If you have 100 pages, chances are, you probably going to split that up into several assemblies anyways.  But even if you don't, it really doesn't take very long to compile even a 100 page web application (the pages themselves do not get compiled, it's only the .cs files).  At most this should take 15-20 seconds on a medium powered workstation.

I think you're worrying about something that isn't really that big of a deal.  You're probably more concerned about redeploying, but if you setup your publish system correctly, this is a single click, 10 second thing.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on where you made the change.

If you made the change in a `.cshtml` or similar view file, or other content file (like javascript, css, images, etc.), just uploading the updated file will be sufficient.

If you changed a .cs (or vb, etc.) class however, you will need to recompile.

Comment: So if I have a website say with 100 pages, I have to redo the whole thing?

Comment: It depends on where the change was made.  It's safer to recompile everything as you can be sure you will always have the latest code on your server.

Comment: Is there a way to do this to parts of a website (the class), without compiling the whole application everytime?

Comment: The only way to do that is to split up things into class libraries. You can't change a single code file without recompiling the project in which the code file exists. So no, not really.

Comment: split it into libraries so you can update smaller parts of the site separately.